# Trimming Folder Path of a Url Without Losing First Folder In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets:
I would like to trim a list of urls to first folder

for example:

```
url.com/folder1/xxx/index.html

url.com/folder2/

url.com/folder3/xxx/yyyy/index.html

url.com/folder4/zzz/aaa/bbb/index.html
```

Output should look like this:

```
url.com/folder1/

url.com/folder2/

url.com/folder3/

url.com/folder4/
```

I need to find a formula I can use in Google Sheets, which easily takes care of this all at once for at least 10,000 urls?

I found this tool https://regex101.com/r/aS7zX3/3
However, it does not work when you enter more than 1000 urls.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NEW** answer because you comment "*the case when the url is "es-la.domain.com/peter.75054"* "

With this formula everything is correct

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"\w+.\w+/\w+")))`

[image]

---

**OLD** answer

You think correct and have correct formula in regex101.

You can make it for Google Sheets also

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"^([^\/]*\/[^\/]*)")))`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230324/discussion-on-answer-by-swen-trimming-folder-path-of-a-url-without-losing-first).