# Extract data from different google sheets using QUERY, IMPORTRANGE and TRANSPOSE?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 3 testing files as shown in the screenshot above. I want to import the data from these 3 files into a master google sheet. This is the formula that I'm using:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29");IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B4,"Sheet1!B26:L29");IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B5,"Sheet1!B26:L29")}),"where Col1 is not null"))`

The outcome output of this formula is:
[image]

It works perfectly fine when all the data are filled in 3 source files. However, if the first file (`testing`) is empty, then the output will be `#N/A` in cell `B5` in the master google sheet. May I know how to avoid this situation where the data only come out when the first file is filled with data? I want the formula able to skip the first file if it is empty and continue for the 2nd and the 2rd file.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your range is empty you got error message that is a single cell.
Stacking tables {table;table;table;} is possible only when all the tables have equal number of columns.
If you have 11 columns (from B to L) you should get a row of 11 empty cells in case of error. So each importrange should be wrapped with iferror or ifna formula that returns empty cells:

```
iferror(IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29");{""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""})
```

I've built an example file:
[image]

Here I try to importrange from the same file. In a first row I try to reference non-existing sheet. Second reference is correct.
Iferror makes 2 empty cells to prevent from error.

File is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AnNAlV7mQmXo9vJ6YQugSm2-PS-RQPoND27wwv5f5k/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Dołęgowski, do you mean something like this? `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({IFNA(IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29"));IFNA(IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B4,"Sheet1!B26:L29"));IFNA(IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B5,"Sheet1!B26:L29"))}),"where Col1 is not null"))`, I tried but it still returned `N/A`. Or I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: @weizer - my answer is updated. Please take a look

Comment: THanks Krzysztof Dołęgowski, it works for me now! May I know what does it means by adding `{""/""}` for each `IMPORTRANGE`?

Comment: "" means empty contents \ is a separator between cells. { } is a statement that says "table inside".

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I did not understand from your question what you wanted. I am sorry. You made it not clear.
That is what I asked in comment to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727381/trimming-folder-path-of-a-url-without-losing-first-folder-in-google-sheets#comment117982503_66729252).

Now I see you can **use this formula** with 2 `QUERY`

```
=QUERY(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29");
              IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B4,"Sheet1!B26:L29");
              IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B5,"Sheet1!B26:L29")},
                       "where 1=1"), 
          "where Col1 is not null")
```

It gives you results exactly like you like.
No need for `IFERROR`.
No need for `{""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""}`.
I imagine 10 importrange and 20 columns `Sheet1!B26:T29` and `IFERROR` for every importrange.
10 times this:

```
iferror(IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29");{""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""\""})
```

I go crazy

---

First answer
You also **try this trick**

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B3,"Sheet1!B26:L29");IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B4,"Sheet1!B26:L29");IMPORTRANGE(NameList!B5,"Sheet1!B26:L29")}),"where Col1 is not null or 1=1 "))`

You see i add `or 1=1`
This will stop error `#N/A` in cell `B5` in the master google sheet.

Comment: Hi Swen, I tried to add in `1=1` but it will cause the `QUERY` function not functioning. It will recreate the empty columns which I want to remove using `where Col1 is not null`.

Comment: It is not `1=1`. It is `or 1=1`. It works to me. If not to you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727381/trimming-folder-path-of-a-url-without-losing-first-folder-in-google-sheets#comment117982503_66729252) comment.

Comment: @Swen - it's interesting, but could you explain what exactly "or 1=1" within query makes?